# Using memo with a component that has an array.map and depends on an array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that shows certain movies based on filters but I don't want the table to render the movies everytime the user clicks on a checkbox

this is my code for the table tbody that should be memoized

```
const Tbody = memo(({ pelis, generos }) => {
    return pelis.length > 0 && generos.length > 0 ? (<tbody>
        {pelis.map((p, index) => <tr key={index}>
            <td>{index}</td>
            <td><img src={"http://localhost:5000" + p.imgPath} /></td>
            <td>{p.name}</td>
            <td>{(new Date(p.date)).toLocaleDateString("es-ES", { day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric" })}</td>
            <td>{(generos.find(g => g._id === p.genre).name)}</td>
            <td>{p.subgenre && (generos.find(g => g._id === p.subgenre).name) || "-"}</td>
        </tr>)}
    </tbody>) : null
}, arePropsEqual)

function arePropsEqual(oldProps, newProps) {
    return (
        oldProps.pelis.length === newProps.pelis.length
    )
}
```

[image: admin section of movie portal]

I tried the 2 different approaches with memo but I might be missing something or doing something wrong. I would like to render the tbody only once and then wait for the movies to change before rendering that part again

Comment: Are you sure it's not preventing some rerenders? React.memo is not guaranteed to stop something from rendering more than once. It exists to cut down on the number of unnecessary rerenders. From https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo - "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs."

Comment: I used Ahmed Sbai's solution useMemo and it works. It seems not to work the other way with object arrays it was rendering every single time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you use memo, your component re-renders whenever any prop is not shallowly equal to what it was previously. This means that React compares every prop in your component with the previous value of that prop using the Object.is comparison. Note that Object.is(3, 3) is true, but Object.is({}, {}) is false.
> To get the most out of memo, minimize the times that the props change. For example, if the prop is an object, prevent the parent component from re-creating that object every time by using useMemo:

With useMemo(), we can return memoized values and avoid re-rendering if the dependencies to a function have not changed.

So here it is recommanded to use [`useMemo()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) react hook instead of `memo()`

Note also that your function `arePropsEqual` is not the correct way to compare two arrays, it will ignore updates if the new array has the same length of the old one better is to compore with `JSON.stringigy` :

```js
function arePropsEqual(oldProps, newProps) {
  return JSON.stringify(oldProps) === JSON.stringify(newProps);
}
```

but with `useMemo()` you don't really need it the function is able to compare arrays :

```js
const Tbody = useMemo(()=> {
//...
},[pelis])
```